# What is the closed-form solution to this double-sum norm function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, norms, closed-form-expressions

Given two points $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^2$, one defines the Euclidean distance $f: \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ as  follows.

$$f(A,B) := \Vert A-B \Vert : = \sqrt{(A_{x}-B_{x})^2 + (A_{y} - B_{y})^2}$$

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{> 1}$ be a constant. Assume also two index sets $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ associated with three finite sets of points $\{q_{i}|i \in \mathcal{I}\}$, $\{q_{i}^{0}|i \in \mathcal{I}\}$, and $\{q_{j}|j \in \mathcal{J}\}$. Is there a closed-form solution to the following double-sum term? (By the closed-form, I mean a function of the parameters which does not include any summation symbol).

$$\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}}\sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} \frac{\Vert q_{i}-q_{i}^{0} \Vert^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}{\Vert q_{i}-q_{j} \Vert^{2}}$$

Comment: What does that superscript $T$ mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It is just a label. ($q_{i}$ is the current position of agent $i$, and $q_{i}^{T}$ is target position corresponding to it.)

Comment: Good. A superscript $T$ is often used to denote the transpose of a matrix, but I couldn't see that making any sense here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Does removing that $T$ help getting some answer? Here you go, then!